# How to set two-sided printing as default in Mountain Lion Preview?

Tags: macos, preview, printing

Every time I print from Preview app I need to manually click on "Two-sided" checkbox. This is annoying when I have a bunch of documents to print. Is there any way to set "two-sided" as default?

Comment: for some reason for me the double sided option does not appear in the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the print dialog you should save a new preset. Below you can find the steps to do so.

1. Open the Print dialog. It will look something like this:
   [image]
2. Check the `Two-Sided` box.
   [image]
3. Go to the Presets drop down list and click `Save As...`
   [image]
4. Type a name for the preset in the dialog and choose if you want this preset available for all your installed printers or just this one.
   [image]
5. Now choose that preset in the dropdown list. The next time you will print something the preset will be automatically active, so it will print two-sided as default.

Comment: for some reason for me the double sided option does not appear in the box only when I do it with preview.

Comment: @CharlieParker My instructions are for the Preview application. What is the problem you encounter? Perhaps you can upload a screenshot?

Comment: @CharlieParker Your printer may not be set up properly.